# Get dictionary values without referencing the dictionary every time Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm building a large dictionary from XBRL data in order to automate the generation of custom financial ratios.  The following code works fine, but I was curious if there is a better way to reference the dictionary items without having to write out the dictionary name every time I want to pull a variable from it.

```
FinStatItems = {'GainOnSaleOfRealEstate': 0, 'DepreciationAndAmortization': 104044000.0, 'NetIncome': -4086000.0, 'ImpairmentOnInvestmentsInRealEstate': 122472000.0}
NAREIT_FFO = FinStatItems['NetIncome'] + FinStatItems['DepreciationAndAmortization'] + FinStatItems['ImpairmentOnInvestmentsInRealEstate'] - FinStatItems['GainOnSaleOfRealEstate']

print('NAREIT FFO = ' + str(NAREIT_FFO))
```

Is there a better way to write this line:

```
NAREIT_FFO = FinStatItems['NetIncome'] + FinStatItems['DepreciationAndAmortization'] + FinStatItems['ImpairmentOnInvestmentsInRealEstate'] - FinStatItems['GainOnSaleOfRealEstate']
```

Comment: Better how? Getting a value by key is `O(1)`.

Comment: What's your primary concern here…?

Comment: ```fsi = FinStatItems``` makes it a little easier - ```fsi['xyz']```.

Comment: Thanks!  I think just shortening the variable name will work the best at making this more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is a little code aesthetics then you can use `operator.itemgetter()` which can take a list of args, e.g.:

```
>>> import operator as op
>>> fn = op.itemgetter('NetIncome', 'DepreciationAndAmortization', 'ImpairmentOnInvestmentsInRealEstate')
>>> NAREIT_FFO = sum(fn(FinStatItems)) - FinStatItems['GainOnSaleOfRealEstate']
```

But this will be no more efficient than your original code. And only really useful if you want to reuse `fn()`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help.  I think just shortening the variable name will work best for this particular application.  But itemgetter will probably come in very handy on other parts!

Answer (score 0):

You could reference a list of the items

```
FinStatItems = {'GainOnSaleOfRealEstate': 0, 'DepreciationAndAmortization': 104044000.0, 'NetIncome': -4086000.0, 'ImpairmentOnInvestmentsInRealEstate': 122472000.0}
items = ['NetIncome', 'DepreciationAndAmortization', 'ImpairmentOnInvestmentsInRealEstate', 'GainOnSaleOfRealEstate']
NAREIT_FFO = sum(FinStatItems[item] for item in items[:-1]) - FinStatItems[items[-1]]

print('NAREIT FFO = ' + str(NAREIT_FFO))
```